# select and poll syscalls. many write events problem

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, freebsd

I have a setup with a server/client having many connections to each other. The data being sent in large volumes. The `select` or `poll` system calls return many file descriptors as **being ready for write**. But, as I proceed to write data, eventually, with **Nth** file descriptor I get `EAGAIN`, with zero bytes written. And that continues for the most part.

As I understand for now, it is internal kernel buffer, that gets filled up. So the rest of file descriptors get no data sent at the `syscall` wake up.

My question is, do all file descriptors get signalled in fair fashion? What I mean is, from total of number of file descriptors, first group get signaled and are moved to the **tail** of **avaible for write** queue. If not, then how to overcome the above, how to make so, that all sockets that need a data transfer will receive a fair amount of attention?

And as a result of a question, can I skip event loop, if the `EAGAIN` start to come up?

I do program in C, code references and explanations are welcome.

Comment: I would expect FIFO behavior, and that you want to process whatever file descriptors are ready before you iterate your event loop.

Comment: @AllanWind Thank you for the suggestion. I did add OS specific tags.

Comment: Linux doesn't give you EAGAIN when full per man page (it says other unix operating systems do).  I know nothing about freebsd.

Comment: @AllanWind I can not run Linux, as of now. Looking at the internet manpages for `Linux` I saw nothing more appropriate except `EAGAIN`. So I had placed the error code for simplicity of reading.

Comment: You tagged your question linux which is why I mentioned it.  From select(2) "On  some  other UNIX systems, select() can fail with the error EAGAIN if the system fails to allocate kernel-internal resources, rather than ENOMEM as Linux does.  POSIX specifies this error for poll(2),  but  not  for select().  Portable programs may wish to check for EAGAIN and loop, just as with EINTR."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, do all file descriptors get signalled in fair fashion?

Both `poll` and `select` will return information on which file descriptors are *currently* readable/writable as of the instant the call returns.  This is "fair" in that they are all indicated simultansously.  You will need to loop over all the descriptors and write to each one that is writable.  You can decide to prefer some over others if you wish, or arrange for your loop to be more fair.

When you `write` to a descriptor, it will return `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` for any one that is non-blocking and has no buffer space.  Each fd has its own buffer, so this happening on one fd has nor bearing on any other fds and they may still be writable.

Comment: I think I need to test the situation more in real applications. Will return to the question some time later.